# Excel VBA double click function that alternates two texts

Tags: excel, vba, double-click

I am trying to create Excel VBA code in a cell that alternates 'IN' and 'OUT' by double clicking the cell.
It looks like I have to use: **Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, cancel As Boolean)** in the Sheet1 rather than in a module.

In the same Sheet1, I already have same function in another cell that alternates 'In Operation', 'Failing', and 'Not Operational', which works great.

When I try to copy the code and execute with different range name, I get the compile error message of 'ambiguous name detected.'

How can I go about to avoid the error message and make this work?

Any help wile very appreciated.

Comment: Help us to help you, **post your current code.**

Comment: You dont need to copy the function, but to test the `Target` range that comes in as parameter and act accordingly

Answer (score 0):

The Workbook Codemodule receives events for all the Worksheets

### Workbook Codemodule

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetBeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Sh Is Sheet1 Then
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A5")) Is Nothing Then
            Target.Value = IIf(Target.Value = "OUT", "IN", "OUT")
            Cancel = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Alternatively, you could just pass the `DoubleCLick` event parameters to a sub.  Make sure that you pass `Cancel` `ByRef` so that you can stop the cell from being edited.

### Sheet1 Codemodule

Sub Sheet1BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, ByRef Cancel As Boolean)

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A5")) Is Nothing Then
    Target.Value = IIf(Target.Value = "OUT", "IN", "OUT")
    Cancel = True
End If
```

End Sub

### Standard Codemodule

Sub Sheet1BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, ByRef Cancel As Boolean)

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A5")) Is Nothing Then
    Target.Value = IIf(Target.Value = "OUT", "IN", "OUT")
    Cancel = True
End If
```

End Sub